# How to catch a value from system dialog in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dialog

is there any possibility to catch a value from the system dialog in Flutter? I mean, I have a screen-sharing feature in-app, and when I want to start sharing the screen system shows me the dialog shown below. It's not a dialog created by me, because it's a system dialog. Could I catch eg. the 'Cancel' value somehow?

[image]

Comment: Hum, you want to see if you have the permission to use "Recording or casting" on your app after the dialog? If yes, how do you ask the permission?

Comment: which plugin are you using for casting? On native side, you can get it. More info https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/CastStatusCodes#CANCELED